# Saving my all iMessage conversations to Windows 10

Tags: ipod-touch

I need to save my iMessage conversations as they are, because I'm afraid all the updated dialogue will be erased as soon a I restore my iPod from a previous backup.  The restoring of the iPod will happen, I just don't want to lose any dialogue from this very second until the last time I backed up my iPod. The conversation is very long and very important to me, and I need to keep all of it.  I am not looking to add an unknown, potentially hazardous software of program.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.
Thank you for you time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

I use [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer), which is available for macOS and for Windows. Among other highly useful things, it can [export the contents of Messages](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer/export-iphone-messages-voicemail-contacts), including images. It it not a free app, but I've used it so many times that it has paid for itself (US$39.99) many times over.

*Disclaimer*: Satisfied user - not affiliated in any way with Macroplant LLC.

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy response.  It looks like I'll have to bit the proverbial bullet and pay for a third party program.  Thank you again IconDaemon.